# Nested enums which conform to Equatable protocol produce error

Tags: swift, enums

I have a protocol named `TableViewItem`. This protocol enforces that conforming objects implement a `type` property, which has the protocol `TableViewCellIdentifiable` as its type. `TableViewCellIdentifiable` is used to group three nested enums together, as shown below:

```
internal protocol TableViewCellIdentifiable: Equatable { }

internal enum TableViewCellType {
    internal enum PortfolioSelection: String, TableViewCellIdentifiable {
        case portfolio = "portfolioTableViewCell"
        case enterPortfolioDetails = "enterPortfolioDetailsTableViewCell"
        case addPortfolio = "actionTableViewCell"
    }

    internal enum EditPortfolio: String, TableViewCellIdentifiable {
        case editPortfolioName = "editPortfolioNameTableViewCell"
        case deletePortfolio = "deletePortfolioTableViewCell"
    }

    internal enum Portfolio: String, TableViewCellIdentifiable {   
        case portfolioAsset = "portfolioAssetTableViewCell"
        case addAsset = "actionTableViewCell"
    }
}
```

Here is an example of how this is being used:

```
internal final class EditPortfolioNameTableViewItem: TableViewItem {

    // MARK: - Internal Properties

    internal let type: TableViewCellIdentifiable = TableViewCellType.EditPortfolio.editPortfolioName
    internal let viewModel: TableViewCellModel

    // MARK: - Initialization

    internal init(viewModel: EditPortfolioNameTableViewCellModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, on the line that I am declaring the `type` property, I receive the following error:

> Protocol 'TableViewCellIdentifiable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

I have read through other questions/answers from others who have encountered this error but I can't quite understand why this particular implementation is problematic, and what the solution would be. I know that `Equatable` is the source of the problem, however this is crucial to the functionality, as the enums serve two purposes:

1. To provide reuse identifiers for the table view cells (the raw values).
2. To allow types to be compared - i.e:

   ```
   self.tableViewItems.contains(where: { $0.type == item.type })
   ```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated, even if it means taking an alternative approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained by Honey's answer, `TableViewCellIdentifiable` doesn't provide enough type information for the compiler to work with. You could potentially adopt a different approach which changes the structure a bit (and is potentially overkill), but provides the functionality you're looking for:

```
internal protocol ValueAssociated { }

internal extension ValueAssociated {

    fileprivate var association: (label: String, value: Any?)? {
        get {
            let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
            if let association = mirror.children.first, let label = association.label {
                return (label, association.value)
            }
            return nil
        }
    }
}

internal protocol CellIdentifiable {

    var rawValue: String { get }
}

internal enum CellType: Equatable, ValueAssociated {

    case portfolio(PortfolioIdentifier)
    case portfolioSelection(PortfolioSelectionIdentifier)
    case editPortfolio(EditPortfolioIdentifier)

    internal var identifier: String? {
        return (self.association?.value as? CellIdentifiable)?.rawValue
    }

    internal enum PortfolioIdentifier: String, Equatable, CellIdentifiable {

        case portfolioAsset = "portfolioAssetTableViewCell"
        case addAsset = "actionTableViewCell"
    }

    internal enum PortfolioSelectionIdentifier: String, Equatable, CellIdentifiable {

        case portfolio = "portfolioTableViewCell"
        case enterPortfolioDetails = "enterPortfolioDetailsTableViewCell"
        case addPortfolio = "actionTableViewCell"
    }

    internal enum EditPortfolioIdentifier: String, Equatable, CellIdentifiable {

        case editPortfolioName = "editPortfolioNameTableViewCell"
        case deletePortfolio = "deletePortfolioTableViewCell"
    }
}
```

This can be used as follows:

```
internal let cellType: CellType = .portfolio(.portfolioAsset)
print(cellType.identifier!) // Prints "portfolioAssetTableViewCell"
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

In your head, should the following code compile?

```
var x : Equatable
```

It shouldn't. Why?

Because if you had:

```
var x : Equatable 
var y : Equatable
```

Then the compiler can't ensure that x & y are of the same type. `x` can be "John", because "John"/Strings are Equatable...all while `y` can be `10`, because 10/integers are equatable.

and the compiler would suspect that a few lines below you might want to do

```
if x == y { print ("equal" }
```

which it can't process. So it just stops you from ever doing it in the beginning.

---

The following line of your code will trigger the same error because of the reason above.

```
internal let type: TableViewCellIdentifiable = TableViewCellType.EditPortfolio.editPortfolioName
```